# Spring Reactive List of Mono to Flux

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I have a

```
list.stream()
.map(element -> func());
```

where func() returns with Mono. What is the easiest way to convert this list of `Mono<CustomObject>` objects to `Flux<CustomObject>` and return it from the stream?

Comment: You can take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843767/proper-way-to-create-a-flux-from-a-list-of-monos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
List<Mono<CustomObject >> monoList = new ArrayList<>();
monoList(object);

Flux<CustomObject> flux = Flux.concat(monoList);
```

Comment: Hi vijay, can you add a little context around your code sample?

Comment: Flux<CustomObject> != Flux<Mono<CustomObject>>

Comment: Please comment your code so the person you are trying to help can understand what the code does and how it solves their problem.

Comment: Please comment your code so the person you are trying to help can understand what the code does and how it solves their problem.

Comment: 1. Mono<SomeClass> is basically a data item emitted (sequential) by a source at a given point of time. monoList is a collection of such Monos wherein the list contains multiple data items emitted by a downstream system & added to a collection (List in this case). Similarly, there could one or more such sources emitting items sequentially which means more than one list of Mono<SomeClass> exists.

2. Combine each one of sources to make a continuous stream of all the data items.
Consideration: Subscribe to multiple data sources sequentially or eagerly ?
a. concat: sequential
b. merge: eager

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Flux.concat` ([Documentation here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-)):

```
var yourCode = list.stream().map(element -> func());
var whatyouWant = Flux.concat(yourCode);
```

From the documentation:

> `public static <T> Flux<T> concat(Iterable<? extends Publisher<? extends T>> sources)`
>
> Concatenate all sources provided in an Iterable, forwarding elements emitted by the sources downstream.

So basically `concat` takes an Iterable of `Publisher` (which `Mono` is) and return a `Flux` for the type you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an operation that maps a `List<T>` to a `List<Mono<U>>` then you can convert the original `List<T>` into a `Flux<T>`, for example.

Instead of:

```
List<T> entities = ArrayList<>();
List<Mono<U>> monos = entities.map (this::operationThatReturnsMono);
```

You can do something like:

```
List<T> entities = ArrayList<>();
Flux<U> flux = Flux.fromIterable(entities).flatMap(this::operationThatReturnsMono)
```